# Preventing execution of subsequent event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple event bindings on an element, say `#myDiv`:

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    // Do something
});

$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    // Do something more
});

$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    // Do something more
});
```

What I want to do is create a *validation binding* so that the further bindings are executed only if the validation succeeds. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/2SEdF):

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    var error = false;
    // ... Validate
    error = true;
    if(error) {
        // Stop further bindings. (So 'Success!' won't be appended.)
        e.stopPropagation(); // This won't work
        return false;
    }
});

/*
 * I cannot change this function, and this must execute only if error == false
 * in the previous binding. 
 */
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    $(this).append(" Success!");
});
```

---

[One obvious way to do this](http://jsfiddle.net/RMLqH/1/) would be create a global variable called `error`, and add a condition in all bindings to not execute if `error == true`:

```
var error = false;

// validate
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    ...
    error = true;
});

$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    if(error) return false;
    // Do something
});

$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    if(error) return false;
    // Do something more
});
```

**But is there a way to prevent further execution without adding the if condition in all the bindings?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    var error = false;
    // ... Validate
    error = true;
    if(error) {
        // Stop further bindings. (So 'Success!' won't be appended.)
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you re looking for is  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
this will prevent any other handler to run after this event.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/astuanax/7S6qs/2/

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    var error = false;
    // ... Validate
    error = true;
    if(error){
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

In the example, you can set the value of the error to false, which will trigger the 3th event handler. If set to true, nothing happens and none of the handlers are triggered.

The jquery docuemntation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/